# Angular routing not working correctly on hosted app

Tags: angular, web-hosting

i hosted my app on strato, but the routing won't work correct.

from ...myapp.com it works within the app when I click buttons which redirect me to other components but not if i type in some paths like ...myapp.com/home.

these are my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: "home", component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'user-information', component: UserInformationComponent},
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {path: '**', component: HomeComponent}
];
```

when I type in some random path:

[image]

Comment: You need to set up your server to redirect all 404 requests to index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in app-routing-module you have to add { enableTracing: false, useHash: true} in @NgModule

```
@NgModule({imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: false, useHash: true})],  exports: [RouterModule]})
```

if you need to make default route you can use

```
{path: '**' , component: YourComponent}
```

Comment: It worked. but with a "#" in between. I already added a wildcard. thank you so much.